# Counting the roots of nonlinear systems of equations

Tags: soft-question, roots, vector-analysis, systems-of-equations

I have a "nice" function (vector field)
$$\mathbf{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$
and I need to find how many roots (zeros) it has in a certain domain (hopefully prove that it has at most one).  I do not have the function in explicit form, but I can infer some properties such as being continuously differentiable, bounded (by individual vector components), and each component of the vector $\mathbf{f}$ changing monotonically along a corresponding axis.

**Are there any theorems that could be helpful in this, i.e. proving that the system has no more than one root in some domain?**

This is for an actual practical application related to physics.  Anything that works for $n=2$ only is useful, but I'm also interested in $n>2$ (only small $n$ in practice, i.e. $3,4,5,6$).

Comment: If you have a contraction map, then it has at most 1 root.

Comment: @Calvin Thank you, yes, these are the kinds of suggestions I am looking for.  Unfortunately I don't think I can use this particular one.  The arguments of the function and the values of the function are of fundamentally different types (physically) and I can't directly compare them (meaning I can't in practice have the same domain and codomain as required by a contraction mapping).